# PL/SQL Procedures and Toad execution?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, toad

I recently started working on a number of large Oracle PL/SQL stored procedures with Toad for Oracle. Number of these procedures updates and inserts stuff into tables. My question is, is there a way to "safely" execute PL/SQL procedures without permanently modifying any of the tables ? Also, how do I safely modify and execute stored procedures for experimentation without actually making changes to the database ?

Comment: `PL/SQL procedures` are meant to perform some of the actions. Those may include population and modification of tables. And if you don't want to see those changes in table then what's the point running the procedure.

Comment: @XING Of course, I understand that. But some of these procedures are well over 3000 lines long - as a newbie, I don't feel comfortable just running them without understanding if any tables are going to be left in an inconsistent state...

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't matter if you have Toad or SQ*Plus or anything really - it's all about the code.

First - does your program have any commits or rollbacks IN the stored procedures?

Second - does your program do any DDL work: create a table? That will do an implicit COMMIT. Mind you, if your program calls another program and THAT program has a COMMIT or DDL - you're COMMITTED as its' all in one session.

Third - when you go to execute your stored procedure, does your anonymous block have a COMMIT or ROLLBACK there?

Your tool comes into play for the third bit. Inspect the code behind the 'execute' button.

In SQL Developer (similar to Toad in this regard)...

In this case my SP has a commit in the code - so barring an exception before that line...it's a permanent change.

In the generated anonymous block, there's a ROLLBACK, but it's commented out. When you hit the execute button in your GUI, look at the code there. Change it if necessary.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a copy of your database, then play there. Other thing is, you can create a copy of the procedures/functions, packages and tables involve and play with it.

Let's you have this procedure,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc1
IS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table1
    (col1, col2)
    VALUES
    ('actual data', 'hello');
    UPDATE table2
       SET col1 = 'actual'
     WHERE col2 = 1;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

You will create new procedure with same logic inside it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc1_test
IS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table1_test
    (col1, col2)
    VALUES ('test', 'hello');
    UPDATE table2_test
       SET col1 = 'test2'
     WHERE col2 = 1;
    COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Doing this, it will let you compare your actual data to your test data.

Comment: When you said "create a copy", I thought that you were suggesting a new user, in development environment. A "copy" you suggest is somewhat doubtful; what if you "forget" to modify one of those table names?

Comment: We'll, that's a good point, Thanks. If OP follow my answer,  he/she should checked if all tables in the procedure were already modified before executing those "copied" procedures or functions.

Comment: Certainly, but "what if" remains. Personally, I'd rather have a development environment, but we're just discussing.

Comment: I agree with that. That's why, in the first sentence of my answer I said, "You can create a copy of your database, then play there."

Answer (score 0):

You can put rollback at the end of the procedure and comment any Commits/DDL statements. Also you need to be careful for the Pragma statements if any.